# Create a 2D plane tessellation starting from given centroids

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, centroid, tessellations

I have a problem: I want to find a method which, given *a set of centroids* as `x,y` coordinates (the number of the centroids does not matter, more than one) it returns me a tessellation of the plane such that **each region has the center of mass exactly at one of the given centroids.**

It is similar to the Centroidal Voronoi Tessellation (CVT) ([wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation), [slides here](https://kmh-lanl.hansonhub.com/uncertainty/meetings/gunz03vgr.pdf), [library here](https://idaes-pse.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.0/explanations/modeling_extensions/surrogate/sampling/pysmo_cvt.html)), yet I would like to generate it given the centroids, and not starting from the image and the number of centroids (as in the all other examples provided). Usually it is built by iteratively moving the centroids, while I would like to build it by **iteratively growing the regions such that each centroid remains the centroid of each region**.

If we grow the regions towards the center, they will touch each other. We can then stop one and continue the others, until we reach the end where we have (given $N$ starting centroids) $N$ regions, which do not have empty space between them (but can have *empty space outside them*, no need to fill a square).

Do you know of any algorithm capable of doing that or any idea on how to implement/get it to work?

PS: it may be an NP-hard problem.

Edit: I show an example image, in this case a handcrafted example:
[image: handcrafted example]

So here, I created a grid on an empty plane, chose (randomly) some centers and created pieces (in this case regular symmetric polygon, which makes it easier for me) whose center of mass is exactly the center (highlighted in blue). But this is (slowly) made by hand. I am asking if there is a way to compute this systematically and with irregular shapes, without having the constraint of using only regular symmetric polygons!
Can it be done using some modified version of the known tessellations (or maybe I missed the existing one doing already this?)

In this case I tessellated only a part of the plane, yes (@Ivan Neretin) it is not important. The target would be to have no space between the pieces (we are creating puzzles).

Comment: There is an awful lot of ambiguity in the word "similar". Let's be exact: do you want your tesselation to be a **Voronoi tesselation** (which not every polygonal tesselation is), and if yes, do you want it to be a **centroidal Voronoi tesselation** (probably no, because that would be generally impossible)?

Comment: Sorry about that. The voronoi part is not important: I don't have any constraint on the size or shape of the regions, the only constrain is on the center of mass. The center of mass of the created regions should be on the centroid (given before). I thought the CVT would do that, but the centroids of the created regions are different from the original centroids. The comparison with CVT was only to help understand and visualize the problem, sorry if it distracted you.

Comment: What part of the plane do we tesselate? Obviously not all of it, right? I would imagine that some bounding box is given. Well, then what do we do in cases like this: $$\fbox{$\mathstrut\cdot \cdot~~~~~~~$}$$

Comment: Hi @IvanNeretin, I did not get your point. It would be good to tessellate all the plane, but it is not required, we can leave some empty space. You can even forget the plane, just imagine having a list of centers `( (0,3), (3,2), (6,4) )` (these are random numbers). The question is: can you create three irregular shapes such that they tessellates the space whose centers are exactly the one given above? If the three shapes tessellates the space between `0` and `10` (in both `x` and `y` axis) is fine, if between `0` and `8` also fine. The input should be the centroids, this is the hardest part.

Comment: If you are given as centroids `( (0,0), (0,2), (0,4) )` one possible solution is to return squares of side `2` with their centers exactly in these places, yes. If that was your question. I see no problem with that, if the algorithm returns that solution. It's probably the easiest case. But if we change the centroids, the algorithm should still generate a valid tessellations. Is it more clear now?

Comment: A plane is infinite; how would you tesselate it without at least some infinite parts? And if we only tesselate some finite area, then what area is that? Do we get to chose it ourselves?

Comment: Are you arguing to prove your point or to understand the question? Because I don't get what your questions are about. I already explained, the centroids are given, the plane not. Let some parts be infinite, or let's define a finite plan of the size you wish. Choose it yourself, is fine, it will not affect what I am looking for. Do you have any idea about how to divide the (finite) pars or are you just arguing for fun?

Comment: I am definitely not trying to prove a point, since I don't have a point. It could be _"Well, let's try such-and-such approach"_, or it could be _"Your question is ill-posed and can't be answered"_, and I can't decide which one is it, because you don't give enough information. The centroids are given, I got that; now what is the area that we tesselate? Just any area that we want?

Comment: Yes, just any area you want. I am sorry about information, but we do not have more information. We also have this problem deciding between what to try or just let it go because it cannot be done. But manually as a human it feels doable iteratively (I did it manually for some examples as the above one). So I think there should be a way. Choose any area you want and anyway an idea or pseudo-code or algorithm about tessellation would be helpful. Thanks a lot for the discussion!